# Mapping the value of json response array to a predefined interface

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I want to map the value of JSON response to the following interface:

```
export interface CyHourlyWeather {
    temperature: string;
    skycon: string;
    precipitation: number;
    wind: {
        speed: number,
        direction: number
    },
    cloudrate: number
}
```

I want to map the server response into an `HourlyWeather: Array<CyHourlyWeather>`, so that the array may contain multiple `CyHourlyWeather`. However, the data structure of the array is complicated - I cannot think of a way to filter and map these data.

JSON response:

```
 "result":{
        "status":"ok",
        "hourly":{ 
            "status":"ok",
            "temperature":[ 
                {
                    "value":8.0,
                    "datetime":"2015-09-28 13:00"
                },
                {},
            ] // e.g. 1hr, 2hr, 3hr... 
            "skycon": [{"value": ..., "datetime": ...}, {}],
            "precipitation": [{"value": ..., "datetime": ... }, {}],
            "wind": [{"speed": ..., "direction": ...}, {}],
            "cloudrate": [{"value": ..., "datetime": ... }, {}],
        }
  }
```

I know how to retrieve data (e.g. getting a specific value) and do simple mapping (e.g. map the response as a single onject but not as an array), but when I try to apply some javascript array (forEach...) and iterative functions, it just somehow fails. Any suggestions on how to implement this?

**Edit - What I have tried:**

```
this.caiyunForecastService.getCaiyunForecast()
  .subscribe( val => this.hourlyWeather = val.map(element => {
    return <CyHourlyWeather> {
      temperature: element.result.hourly.temperature.value,
      skycon: element.result.hourly.skycon.value,
      precipitation: element.result.hourly.precipitation.value,
      wind: {
        speed: element.result.hourly.wind.speed,
        direction: element.result.hourly.wind.direction
      },
      cloudrate: element.result.hourly.cloudrate.value
    }
  }));
```

This returns a val.map is not a function and fails.

Edit 2 - A longer sample response

```
"result":{
        "status":"ok",
        "hourly":{ 
            "status":"ok",
            "pm25":[ //pm25
                {
                    "value":8.0,
                    "datetime":"2015-09-28 13:00"
                },
                {
                    "value":8.0,
                    "datetime":"2015-09-28 14:00"
                },
                {
                    "value":7.0,
                    "datetime":"2015-09-28 15:00"
                },
                {
                    "value":3.0,
                    "datetime":"2015-09-28 16:00"
                },
                {
                    "value":-0.0,
                    "datetime":"2015-09-28 17:00"
                },
                {
                    "value":-0.0,
                    "datetime":"2015-09-28 18:00"
                },
                {
                    "value":-0.0,
                    "datetime":"2015-09-28 19:00"
                },
                {
                    "value":-0.0,
                    "datetime":"2015-09-28 20:00"
                },
                {
                    "value":-0.0,
                    "datetime":"2015-09-28 21:00"
                },
                {
                    "value":-0.0,
                    "datetime":"2015-09-28 22:00"
                },
                {
                    "value":-0.0,
                    "datetime":"2015-09-28 23:00"
                },
                {
                    "value":-0.0,
                    "datetime":"2015-09-29 00:00"
                },
                {
                    "value":-0.0,
                    "datetime":"2015-09-29 01:00"
                },
                {
                    "value":-0.0,
                    "datetime":"2015-09-29 02:00"
                },
                {
                    "value":-0.0,
                    "datetime":"2015-09-29 03:00"
                },
                {
                    "value":-0.0,
                    "datetime":"2015-09-29 04:00"
                },
                {
                    "value":-0.0,
                    "datetime":"2015-09-29 05:00"
                },
                {
                    "value":-0.0,
                    "datetime":"2015-09-29 06:00"
                },
                {
                    "value":-0.0,
                    "datetime":"2015-09-29 07:00"
                },
                {
                    "value":-0.0,
                    "datetime":"2015-09-29 08:00"
                },
                {
                    "value":-0.0,
                    "datetime":"2015-09-29 09:00"
                },
                {
                    "value":-0.0,
                    "datetime":"2015-09-29 10:00"
                },
                {
                    "value":-0.0,
                    "datetime":"2015-09-29 11:00"
                },
                {
                    "value":-0.0,
                    "datetime":"2015-09-29 12:00"
                },
                {
                    "value":-0.0,
                    "datetime":"2015-09-29 13:00"
                },
                {
                    "value":-0.0,
                    "datetime":"2015-09-29 14:00"
                },
                {
                    "value":-0.0,
                    "datetime":"2015-09-29 15:00"
                },
                {
                    "value":-0.0,
                    "datetime":"2015-09-29 16:00"
                },
                {
                    "value":-0.0,
                    "datetime":"2015-09-29 17:00"
                },
                {
                    "value":-0.0,
                    "datetime":"2015-09-29 18:00"
                },
                {
                    "value":-0.0,
                    "datetime":"2015-09-29 19:00"
                },
                {
                    "value":-0.0,
                    "datetime":"2015-09-29 20:00"
                },
                {
                    "value":-0.0,
                    "datetime":"2015-09-29 21:00"
                },
                {
                    "value":-0.0,
                    "datetime":"2015-09-29 22:00"
                },
                {
                    "value":-0.0,
                    "datetime":"2015-09-29 23:00"
                },
                {
                    "value":-0.0,
                    "datetime":"2015-09-30 00:00"
                },
                {
                    "value":-0.0,
                    "datetime":"2015-09-30 01:00"
                },
                {
                    "value":-0.0,
                    "datetime":"2015-09-30 02:00"
                },
                {
                    "value":-0.0,
                    "datetime":"2015-09-30 03:00"
                },
                {
                    "value":-0.0,
                    "datetime":"2015-09-30 04:00"
                },
                {
                    "value":-0.0,
                    "datetime":"2015-09-30 05:00"
                },
                {
                    "value":3.0,
                    "datetime":"2015-09-30 06:00"
                },
                {
                    "value":8.0,
                    "datetime":"2015-09-30 07:00"
                },
                {
                    "value":14.0,
                    "datetime":"2015-09-30 08:00"
                },
                {
                    "value":19.0,
                    "datetime":"2015-09-30 09:00"
                },
                {
                    "value":24.0,
                    "datetime":"2015-09-30 10:00"
                },
                {
                    "value":29.0,
                    "datetime":"2015-09-30 11:00"
                },
                {
                    "value":33.0,
                    "datetime":"2015-09-30 12:00"
                }
            ],

            "description":"\u66b4\u96e8\u6e10\u5927\uff0c\u4eca\u5929\u665a\u95f421\u70b9\u949f\u540e\u5927\u96e8\uff0c\u5176\u540e\u9634",
            "skycon":[  
                {
                    "value":"RAIN",
                    "datetime":"2015-09-28 13:00"
                },
                {
                    "value":"RAIN",
                    "datetime":"2015-09-28 14:00"
                },
                {
                    "value":"RAIN",
                    "datetime":"2015-09-28 15:00"
                },
                {
                    "value":"RAIN",
                    "datetime":"2015-09-28 16:00"
                },
                {
                    "value":"RAIN",
                    "datetime":"2015-09-28 17:00"
                },
                {
                    "value":"RAIN",
                    "datetime":"2015-09-28 18:00"
                },
                {
                    "value":"RAIN",
                    "datetime":"2015-09-28 19:00"
                },
                {
                    "value":"RAIN",
                    "datetime":"2015-09-28 20:00"
                },
                {
                    "value":"RAIN",
                    "datetime":"2015-09-28 21:00"
                },
                {
                    "value":"RAIN",
                    "datetime":"2015-09-28 22:00"
                },
                {
                    "value":"RAIN",
                    "datetime":"2015-09-28 23:00"
                },
                {
                    "value":"RAIN",
                    "datetime":"2015-09-29 00:00"
                },
                {
                    "value":"RAIN",
                    "datetime":"2015-09-29 01:00"
                },
                {
                    "value":"RAIN",
                    "datetime":"2015-09-29 02:00"
                },
                {
                    "value":"RAIN",
                    "datetime":"2015-09-29 03:00"
                },
                {
                    "value":"RAIN",
                    "datetime":"2015-09-29 04:00"
                },
                {
                    "value":"RAIN",
                    "datetime":"2015-09-29 05:00"
                },
                {
                    "value":"RAIN",
                    "datetime":"2015-09-29 06:00"
                },
                {
                    "value":"RAIN",
                    "datetime":"2015-09-29 07:00"
                },
                {
                    "value":"RAIN",
                    "datetime":"2015-09-29 08:00"
                },
                {
                    "value":"RAIN",
                    "datetime":"2015-09-29 09:00"
                },
                {
                    "value":"RAIN",
                    "datetime":"2015-09-29 10:00"
                },
                {
                    "value":"CLOUDY",
                    "datetime":"2015-09-29 11:00"
                },
                {
                    "value":"CLOUDY",
                    "datetime":"2015-09-29 12:00"
                },
                {
                    "value":"CLOUDY",
                    "datetime":"2015-09-29 13:00"
                },
                {
                    "value":"CLOUDY",
                    "datetime":"2015-09-29 14:00"
                },
                {
                    "value":"CLOUDY",
                    "datetime":"2015-09-29 15:00"
                },
                {
                    "value":"CLOUDY",
                    "datetime":"2015-09-29 16:00"
                },
                {
                    "value":"CLOUDY",
                    "datetime":"2015-09-29 17:00"
                },
                {
                    "value":"CLOUDY",
                    "datetime":"2015-09-29 18:00"
                },
                {
                    "value":"CLOUDY",
                    "datetime":"2015-09-29 19:00"
                },
                {
                    "value":"CLOUDY",
                    "datetime":"2015-09-29 20:00"
                },
                {
                    "value":"CLOUDY",
                    "datetime":"2015-09-29 21:00"
                },
                {
                    "value":"CLOUDY",
                    "datetime":"2015-09-29 22:00"
                },
                {
                    "value":"CLOUDY",
                    "datetime":"2015-09-29 23:00"
                },
                {
                    "value":"CLOUDY",
                    "datetime":"2015-09-30 00:00"
                },
                {
                    "value":"CLOUDY",
                    "datetime":"2015-09-30 01:00"
                },
                {
                    "value":"CLOUDY",
                    "datetime":"2015-09-30 02:00"
                },
                {
                    "value":"CLOUDY",
                    "datetime":"2015-09-30 03:00"
                },
                {
                    "value":"CLOUDY",
                    "datetime":"2015-09-30 04:00"
                },
                {
                    "value":"CLOUDY",
                    "datetime":"2015-09-30 05:00"
                },
                {
                    "value":"CLOUDY",
                    "datetime":"2015-09-30 06:00"
                },
                {
                    "value":"CLOUDY",
                    "datetime":"2015-09-30 07:00"
                },
                {
                    "value":"CLOUDY",
                    "datetime":"2015-09-30 08:00"
                },
                {
                    "value":"CLOUDY",
                    "datetime":"2015-09-30 09:00"
                },
                {
                    "value":"CLOUDY",
                    "datetime":"2015-09-30 10:00"
                },
                {
                    "value":"CLOUDY",
                    "datetime":"2015-09-30 11:00"
                },
                {
                    "value":"CLOUDY",
                    "datetime":"2015-09-30 12:00"
                }
            ],
```

And a testing api: https://api.caiyunapp.com/v2/TAkhjf8d1nlSlspN/121.6544,25.1552/forecast.json

Comment: can you please upload full json response

Comment: @Dhawal I have updated the response to make it more clear. The full response is too long and it's not good to post it here.

Comment: richard: Can you show what you have written and what was failing ?

Comment: If you need to map complex data, i would recommend mapping your responses with an adapter pattern. Here is an example: https://blog.florimondmanca.com/consuming-apis-in-angular-the-model-adapter-pattern

Comment: @ShashankVivek updated.

Comment: @J.Pinxten thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this in your CaiyunForecastService.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

export interface CyHourlyWeather {
  temperature: string;
  skycon: string;
  precipitation: number;
  wind: {
    speed: number;
    direction: number;
  };
  cloudrate: number;
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CaiyunForecastService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  public getCaiyunForecast(): Observable<CyHourlyWeather[]> {
    return this.http.get(
      'https://api.caiyunapp.com/v2/TAkhjf8d1nlSlspN/121.6544,25.1552/forecast.json'
    ).pipe(map((res: any) => this.mapResult(res)));
  }

  private mapResult(res): CyHourlyWeather[] {
    const cyHourlyWeatherArray: CyHourlyWeather[] = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < res.result.hourly.temperature.length; i += 1) {
      cyHourlyWeatherArray.push({
        temperature: res.result.hourly.temperature[i].value,
        skycon: res.result.hourly.skycon[i].value,
        precipitation: res.result.hourly.precipitation[i].value,
        wind: {
          speed: res.result.hourly.wind[i].speed,
          direction: res.result.hourly.wind[i].direction
        },
        cloudrate: res.result.hourly.cloudrate[i].value
      });
    }
    return cyHourlyWeatherArray;
  }
}
```

This will return `Observable<CyHourlyWeather[]>` so you can just subscribe and get the CyHourlyWeather array when it resolves. Haven't tested this, let me know if there are any issues.

Note this is adapted from an Ionic v4 project.

Comment: The function seems to return a single CyHourlyWeather. What I want to do is to iterate and return multiple CyHourlyWeather (please see the JSON response above), as the API returns a JSONArray with multiple JSONObject (e.g. [{time: 1hr, value: 12}, {time:2hr, value: 24}]). I believe that if it is of a single object, then your method will work perfectly.

Comment: No problem I think I understand, I'll update the answer.

Comment: So you want an array of CyHourlyWeather objects from the results? I think the object will have to be more complex than just the current CyHourlyWeather, but I'm not sure I understand the results correctly above.

Comment: Can you post more of the actual results so I can get a better idea?

Comment: Yes, I want an array of CyhourlyWeather. I will post the full response above.

Comment: I also add a testing API so that you can actually get the values.

Comment: Cool think I've got it, I'll post an update in a sec.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't really think of using "for" function in javascript... Will accept your answer

Comment: This code seems to produce a cannot read property of undefined error. I have met this type of error before when I didn't initialize an object, or that the data is not passing into the object. But an async function doesn't look applicable here to deal with this error; I have also tried adding "?" to the variables in my interface document. What do you think might be a solution of this?

Comment: Maybe the arrays for each value (e.g. wind, temp, etc.) are not equal in size and so some of the iterations are getting `undefined` for some of the values. My solution assumes that the arrays returned by the API will always be the same length and in the same hourly order.

Comment: Yes, I also think of that, so I change the number of iteration (temperature.length) to a specific value: 12. It still produces this error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188951/discussion-between-simon-brazell-and-z-richard).